# What does the Sage Advice Compendium mean in this example about casting multiple spells in a turn using Action Surge?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions, spellcasting, sage-advice

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=12) has this text:

> If you cast a spell, such as *healing word*, with a bonus action, you can cast another spell with your action, but that other spell must be a cantrip. Keep in mind that this particular limit is specific to spells that use a bonus action. **For instance, if you cast a second spell using Action Surge, you aren’t limited to casting a cantrip with it.**

From [this tweet by rules designer Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/657260788122386432), I understand that if you cast a spell using a bonus action, then cast a cantrip as an action, and then use Action Surge, you can only cast another cantrip with that additional action. However, I don't understand the example they wrote. It seems to be misplaced.

Can anyone elaborate on what is the meaning of their example? Do they mean "If you cast a spell as a normal action (not as a bonus action), and then Action Surge, you can cast another spell on your second action."?

Comment: Related [Can a PC cast additional spells using Action Surge?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94437/can-a-pc-cast-additional-spell-using-action-surge).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Action Surge allows you to cast more than 1 Action Spell in a turn.

However, it only works if you are casting two Action cost spells. In order to cast a Bonus Action spell, the [general spellcasting rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94437/can-a-pc-cast-additional-spell-using-action-surge) dictate what you can do.

They were trying to provide further direction on Action/Bonus Action casting with regard to spellcasting limitations but also state that the exception to that rule is casting two Action cost spells with an Action Surge.

Answer (score 6):

**If you don't cast a spell as a bonus action, you are not limited in what spells you can cast (including using Action Surge).**

The segment you quoted deals with the number of spells a character can cast in one round.

Previously it explains that there is no hard limit but your character's number of available actions impose a practical limit. It goes on to explain about the interaction of Bonus Action casting time spells and 1 Action casting time spells (because that is the most likely way a character will cast more than 1 spell on a turn), then clarifies that the restriction to cantrips is only imposed when using a Bonus Action spell, not a general restriction on casting 2 or more spells in a turn.

Action Surge is presented as an example of a way to cast 2 spells without invoking the "cantrip only" restriction.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a quirk that results from how they restricted casting with bonus actions.

Part of your confusion probably arises from the nonsense that this implies.  *(NautArch and GreySage are both completely right - and I upvoted them -  but I wanted to offer some additional explanation without answering in comments.)*

Let's say you have an action surge (2nd action).  If you want to cast as much as possible with the highest level spells, this is the best you can do:

- use both of your actions to cast non-cantrips; the bonus action can't be used to cast a spell
- use your bonus action to cast any spell; you may only cast cantrips with your 2 actions

It always feels odd to me due to the way that they worded it, that a high-level eldritch fighter can use their highest 2 spell slots and make a melee attack (as a bonus action), but they can't cast a bonus action cantrip and use just 1 of their 2 actions to cast a non-cantrip.  But those are the rules.

Also, a sorcerer can cast a cantrip as an action and quicken a non-cantrip, but can't cast the non-spell as an action and quicken the cantrip.  These are essentially the same, but one is allowed and the other is not.  I think this is the best illustration of how the rule is poorly written.

<-- rules / how I'll play -->

To complete my thought, I wish they had worded the rule like this (and it's how I'll probably play it as DM): When you cast a spell that is not a cantrip as a bonus action, your original action may not be used to cast a spell that is not a cantrip.