# Bonus action spellcasting, does the order of casting matter?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If you cast let's say Magic Missile, and then used your bonus action to Quicken Spell let's say Eldritch Blast, would that not work because of this?:

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a
>   bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven’t
>   already taken a bonus action this turn. You can’t cast another spell
>   during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1
>   action.

If you cast a non-cantrip spell as your action, does that just negate your ability to use spells in your bonus action, cantrip or not?

Or is it in order where you only have to cast a spell with your main action first, and only then can you still have your bonus action?

But then that would mean you still had your bonus action, and since you already cast a spell with your main action, can you then use a bonus action to cast a non-cantrip spell, since it only prohibits the casting of non-cantrip spells after a bonus action spell has been used (and it hasn't been yet)?

Similarly: If you cast a bonus action cantrip first, does that mean you are unable to then cast a non-cantrip spell for your action?

I was always under the assumption that you were only unable to cast non-cantrip spells with either full action or bonus action if the other has already been used to cast a non-cantrip. (hence why Action Surge spellcasting works as that is another full action rather than a bonus action)

In case the question is a bit too badly written by myself to parse, some examples: Are these valid, if not, which of them are?:

1)

> Action: Fireball
>
> Action Surge: Fireball
>
> Bonus Action: Shillelagh

2)

> Action: Fireball
>
> Bonus Action: Shillelagh
>
> Action Surge: Fireball

3)

> Bonus Action: Shillelagh
>
> Action: Fireball
>
> Action Surge: Fireball

Comment: Also related: [Which uses of Bonus-Action spellcasting are legal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133767/33707)