# Casting two cantrips on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

I was wondering if there's a rule against casting 2 cantrips on the same turn, one as an action and another one as a bonus action, to be more specific I'm playing a grave domain cleric and I was wondering if I can use let's say Toll the Dead (as an action) and Spare the Dying to stabilize a party member (as a bonus action) due to the "Circle of Mortality" feature that allows me to use that one cantrip as a bonus action.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you did not do it already, and in case you need further guidance for posting questions and/or answer visit [help]! Happy gaming!

Comment: Related: [Which uses of Bonus-Action spellcasting are legal?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/133767/33707)

Comment: Thank you, that does answer my question.

Answer (score 7):

The [spell casting rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#CastingaSpell) (PHB, page 202) say

> **Bonus Action**
> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

Hence, your case falls exactly under this rule: in your turn you cast [*Spare the dying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spare-the-dying) whose casting time is a bonus action (thanks to your domain), moreover you can still cast [*Toll the dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/toll-the-dead), since it is a cantrip and it has a casting time of one action.