# When was the Action Surge feature description changed to remove mention of "a possible bonus action"?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, fighter, errata

The fighter's Action Surge originally stated:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can push yourself beyond your normal limits for a moment. On your turn, you can take one additional action on top of your regular action and **a possible bonus action**

This mention of "a possible bonus action" has been a source of confusion, as evidenced by this question [Does an Action Surge grant a second bonus action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63845/does-an-action-surge-grant-a-second-bonus-action) and at least four questions that have been marked as duplicates of it.

This is no longer the case. Action Surge now says:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can push yourself beyond your normal limits for a moment. On your turn, you can take one additional action.
>
> Once you use this feature, you must finish a short or long rest before you can use it again.

It is now quite clear that Action Surge does not grant an additional bonus action.

But when did this change occur? I have checked the [most recent *Player's Handbook* errata document](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) and it makes no mention of the change. So when did this change occur and was it documented?

Comment: This is an interesting question.  There were errata early in this edition that weren't as well publicized as the errata for the sixth printing; some of us picked up on them in the SRD when it first came out (True Polymorph including "until dispelled" was one such, there were others).  This might be hard to answer without an insider ... FWIW, in the originally released SRD it retained *On your turn, you can take one additional action on top of your regular action and a possible bonus action*  Which may have covered errata for a couple of the printings before sixth.

Comment: I've marked this as a dupe seeing as how the target question is exclusively about errata that was first published in the November 2018 version that were not in any previous versions and were not mentioned in the errata document. And the answer there lists the specific change asked about here

Comment: @Medix2 That obviously answers the question, but it's technically not a dupe :P

Comment: @Medix2 I don't think it's a dupe, honestly.  The first well publicized errata come out about 2016 with the sixth printing. A 2018 document hardly shows us when the change occurred.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### November 2018

See here:

- [As of the November 2018 core book updates, what changes were made in the latest printings of the PHB that aren't noted in the errata document?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150613)

The answer there only lists changes that first appeared in that same errata (in other words, changes that did not exist prior). Among those listed changes is the wording change to Action Surge. Thus, we can conclude that the Action Surge wording changed along with the November 2018 printing. Furthermore, the answer provides some concrete proof that this is the case:

> Rules designer Jeremy Crawford also confirmed the change in the [November 27, 2018 edition of Dragon+](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaSdPL_pSgE&t=1600) (in which he discussed the errata), describing it as "unhelpful helper text" that caused people to interpret it as saying the opposite of what it actually meant.